# What is $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1},\zeta^t):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Consider the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1},\zeta^t)$, for some positive integer $t$. What is its degree?

Edit: as mentioned in the comments, if $p$ and $t$ are coprime, the degree is just $2$. What about the other cases?

Comment: If $n$ and $t$ are coprime, then $\zeta$ lies in the RHS and hence the degree is $2$. But suppose $t$ and $n$ are not coprime and $t$ does not divide $n$. How do you reduce it to $t|n$?

Comment: Switch to the gcd?

Comment: I don't think it's so easy, as $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ are still dependent on $\zeta$, not $\zeta^{\mathrm{gcd}(t,n)}$, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: In any case, an answer to the question with $t|n$ would be great as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n \leq 2$ then $\zeta = \pm 1$, so the fields you ask about are both $\mathbf Q$.

Now we will assume $n \geq 3$, so $\zeta$ is not real.

Let $u = \zeta + \zeta^{-1}$, which is real.  Then $u\zeta = \zeta^2 + 1$, so $\zeta^2 - u\zeta + 1 = 0$.  Thus $\zeta$ has degree at most $2$ over $\mathbf Q(u)$, and since $\zeta \not\in \mathbf Q(u)$ due to $\zeta$ not being real, $\zeta$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbf Q(u)$.

Since $\mathbf Q(u) \subset \mathbf Q(u,\zeta^t) \subset \mathbf Q(\zeta)$ and $[\mathbf Q(\zeta):\mathbf Q(u)] = 2$, the degree $[\mathbf Q(u,\zeta^t):\mathbf Q(u)]$ is $1$ or $2$, and it is $1$ if and only if $\zeta^t \in \mathbf Q(u)$. The only real roots of unity are $\pm 1$, and $\pm 1$ are in $\mathbf Q(u)$, so $\zeta^t \in \mathbf Q(u)$ if and only if $\zeta^t = \pm 1$, which is equivalent to $\zeta^{2t} = 1$, which is equivalent to $n \mid 2t$. Thus when $n \geq 3$, the field degree $[\mathbf Q(u,\zeta^t):\mathbf Q(u)]$ is $1$ if $n \mid 2t$ and it is $2$ if $n \nmid 2t$.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer.